# i have used datepicker but it always store date like 1970-01-01

Tags: ajax, date, picker

Can any one please help me? I used `date picker` for a date and I also select today but it only stores `1970-01-01`.

```
$("#datepicker-1").datepicker();
});
```

and in php file stored in database:

```
$dt=$_post['date'];
$dt1=date('y-m-d',strtotime($dt));
```

But it stores only `1970-01-01` no matter what date I choose. Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you did to debug? Are you logging in the browser? Can you also show how you're posting to the server?

Comment: I am making a form where there is a field date of joining.in html page <td><input type=text name=date id=datepicker-1/></td>. In php page $dt=$_post['date'];
$dt1=date('y-m-d',strtotime($dt)); insert into reg(date)values('$dt1'); also I want date after a month so I added after$dt1.   $endt=strtotime("+1 month",$dt1); but it shows 0000-00-00